# Returning object as based class: is it a problem?

Tags: c++

Assume I have:

```
class A {
int i;
}

class B : public A {
int j;
A base() { return *this; }
}
```

Is this legal C++ ? Or will I run into slicing problems?

Comment: This is slicing. Why would you think it isn't?

Comment: Not a problem. But you technically don't need that `base` method. You can simply say `A a = b;` and it will implicitly cast.  In almost all uses something that expects an instance of `A` will gladly accept an instance of the derived class `B`.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what ctor is being called here, as it seems that my compiler is making a new instance of type A

Comment: See [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Comment: Yes, it is legal C++, in the sense that no diagnostic is required.   Yes, it does object slicing.   Whether the slicing causes problems depends on what your code, which uses these classes, does with the objects.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this legal C++ ?

Yes.

> Or will I run into slicing problems?

Slicing is exactly what is being done here. Whether there is a problem or not is subjective.

> There is not explicit constructor

There is no need for an explicit constructor since the copy constructor is generated implicitly.

Comment: In that case, how is the object A being built from object B ?
There is not explicit constructor

Comment: @lezebulon  A `B` is an `A` and is implicitly converted to an `A` with no extra effort on your part. That which was `B` is sliced off, ergo the name.

Comment: @lezebulon see edit regarding constructor.